# How is this account older than Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, users

While browsing through Meta SO, I came across the following account: [User Jeremy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1114/jeremy).

The account is currently suspended. However, what caught my attention is the fact that the account was created 15 years, 1 month ago. Stack Overflow was launched on 15th Sep, 2008; which means that SO is 14 years, 11 months old. How is the above account older than SO?

Screenshot of the profile page:
[image]

Comment: ["*On 31 July 2008, Jeff Atwood sent out invitations encouraging his subscribers to take part in the private beta of the new website, limiting its use to those willing to test out the new software. On 15 September 2008 it was announced that the public beta version was in session*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow#History)

Comment: Oh! so that's what it is. This user must have signed up for the private beta. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Hovering the date reveals that Jeremy created the account on August 12, 2008. Based on [the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#page=1&pagesize=500&filter=!-CC*HqP9jrj7n6mK7I7P6sWh1.tA&run=true), Stack Overflow was on Beta since July 31 (as VLAZ already mentioned).

Comment: Of course now I'm wondering what got him suspended for such a long time. Looks like his last meta question (in 2019!!) was about some copyright issue.

Comment: @President James K. Polk: Likely something [on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/224922/43). It doesn't say on Stack Overflow, but on [the other sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/134300/jeremy) it is *"This account is temporarily suspended network-wide. The suspension period ends on Aug 5, 2024 at 15:39. "*.